# Components rendering before Vuex state updates

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm having trouble with vuex getters; On the first log in, with vuex in its initial state, actions which set some state properties are dispatched, however, subsequent usage of getters still retrieve null (the initial value for state properties)

I have the following in my vue component's script:

```js
  beforeCreate() {
    store.dispatch('getSomething', 1).then(() => {
      this.loading = false
    })
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      something: 'getSomething'
    })
  }
```

in the template:

```html
  <v-row v-if="!loading">
  ...
    <span class="text-16">{{ something.name }}</span>
  ...
  </v-row>
```

In the Something store:

```js
const getters = {
    getSomething: state => new Something(
      state.something.id,
      state.something.name,
      state.something.description,
    )
}
```

My expectation is that the action would be called before the component is loaded and being synchronous, the state should be filled by the said action which commits a mutation that sets the state.
Instead I get the following error which points to the getter:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
at getSomething(something.js?62ce:12:1)
```

**Update (mwe)**

```
<template>
  <v-row v-if="!loading">
    <v-col class="mt-3" cols="12" lg="3">
      <base-card>
        <v-row>
          <v-col class="text-center" cols="12">
            <v-avatar>
              <v-icon>mdi-liquid-spot</v-icon>
            </v-avatar>
            <div class="card-title ma-1 text-h5">{{ something.name }}</div>
            <div class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
              <span class="text-16">{{ something.description}}</span>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </base-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import store from "@/store";
import {mapGetters} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  beforeCreate() {
    // getSomething action
    store.dispatch('getSomething', 2).then(() => {
      this.loading = false
    })
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      // getSomething getter
      something: 'getSomething'
    })
  },
  methods: {},
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Where and when do you initialize `state.something`?

Comment: "My expectation is that the action would be called before the component is loaded and being synchronous" - the expectation is wrong, the action is asynchronous by nature, and  you can't prevent the component from being instantiated once it started. It's incorrect to do asynchronous operations in beforeCreate, exactly because it doesn't meet the expectations. `v-if="!loading"` should help against accessing getSomething early. This likely means that it's used in other places. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: @Nechoj I'm setting it in its store module as follows:
`const state = {something: null}`

Comment: But when you never set `something` to non-null value, then you will always get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')` .... You could initialize like `something = {id: undefined, name: undefined, description: undefined}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has (most likely) nothing to do with `vuex`.

This is probably a case of replacing a component with another component of the same type. When that happens, unless the component is `key`-ed using a unique primitive identifier, the component instance is reused (by Vue), so `beforeCreate` is only called once.
After that, whenever the component is updated, the `beforeCreate` hook is no longer called, (only `beforeUpdate` and `updated` hooks are called).

You either `key` the child component using a unique primitive identifier (perhaps `something.id`!?). Or you use `beforeUpdated` hook.

---

Another important aspect is the store action is asynchronous. Do not expect the creation of the component or its mounting to be waiting for the action to resolve. If that's what you want, you should call the action from parent component and condition the rendering of the child component (using `v-if`) on something that gets set when the action has resolved (and which gets unset when you dispatch the action again, to get another *"something"*).

---

If my answer doesn't help you, consider creating a *runnable* [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you posted so far is not enough to create one and test potential solutions.
This makes your question unanswerable, renders it useless for future users having a similar problem and will likely result in the question being closed as *off-topic*.

Comment: The getter and the action have the same name, the dispatch is dispatching the action of the same name

Comment: @njk, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you! I'll update my question to include a mwe

Comment: I've updated my question. According to your answer, what I'm trying to do isn't possible: dispatching and then using the getter within the same template. Instead, I should dispatch the action before entering the component. Is that correct?

Comment: No. You can dispatch the action in `beforeMount()` of the child component. But that component has to have a unique key (typically its `id`). This makes it so that when the `id` changes, a new instance of the component is mounted. If you go with this approach, you need to defend against any error your component/template might throw when the call has not yet returned (so you basically need an alternate "loading" template - which is rendered while the component has mounted but the call to get its data has not yet returned). I hope that's more clear.

Comment: As a side note, you probably don't fully understand what *runnable* [mcve] means. Might be useful to actually open the link and read it. You're supposed to provide a working snippet. One where I can press the Run button and see the code working. You can create one here, using a SO snippet or on jsfiddle or on codesandbox.io (which is actually a node-like online environment, allowing you to use SFC's (single file components).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244233/discussion-between-tao-and-njk18).